# Can I change the accepted Root element of ApexRest?

Tags: apexrest, xml

Possibly a bad question,
I am exposing a simple ApexRest Class to accept post's from an external source.

example bellow:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/user_defined_type_example/*')
global with sharing class MyOwnTypeRestResource {

@HttpPost
global static MyUserDefinedClass echoMyType(MyUserDefinedClass ic) {
    return ic;
}

global class MyUserDefinedClass {

    global String string1;
    global String string2;
    global String string3;

}}
```

Which accepts the input:

```
<request>
<ic>
    <string1>value for string1</string1>
    <string2>value for string2</string2>
    <string3>value for string3</string3>
</ic></request>
```

**Can I change the root `<request>` tag to something else?**

say `<Submission>`

Comment: Even if you do that, you will have an overhead of parsing XML via dom parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the parameterized version of the post body, as you are in your code, it *must* be formatted using `request` as the top-level element. This is true for both the XML- and JSON-based parsing options. If you use `RestContext.request.requestBody` instead, you can choose to create your own format, but you will need to use either `Dom.Document` or `XmlStreamReader` to parse the request yourself.

Comment: Sounds good. In the later case; I would take requestbody's blob.tostring() and then load it into the dom.doc right?

Comment: @RyanSherry Yeah